# Yank in tmux between two editors

Tags: vim, tmux

So, I am trying to copy from one file to another:
- They are both in the same session of tmux

Here is how I get the problem:

```
tmux new -s vim
```

Now I split the window in two:

```
C-b + %
```

And now I open two files in vim, one in each pane. When I try to yank and paste some lines from one file to the other it doesn't work. 
For that I am using the "p" key

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: you are copy/paste between two different vim processes. why not open two files in same vim?

Comment: @Kent, yeah, I am a total noob in vim. I guess that would be a better option

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have different instances of vim running in tmux, then you could copy between them using tmux's copying commands.

For instance:

`ctrl-b [` to enter copying mode

`<space>`, then move around with the arrow keys to highlight some text

`<return>` to finish

`ctrl-b ]` to paste (including in a different window or pane)

Update: See [this blog post](https://awhan.wordpress.com/2010/06/20/copy-paste-in-tmux/) for more details. The exact answer may depend on your key bindings.

Answer (score 0):

You can make the two vim instances share the same clipboard.
First check that your vim supports clipboard by typing `vim --version`, if you see `+clipboard` in the output, then in your `~/.vimrc`, add

```
set clipboard=unnamed
```

now you can freely yank and paste between tmux panes and windows.